# Show $\sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{1-z^k} $diverges outside of the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to prove that  $\sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{1-z^k}$ diverges on ℂ\ $\overline{D(0,1)}$ where $\overline{D(0,1)}$ represents a closed disk of radius 1 centered at 0.

For all $z \epsilon$ ℂ\ $\overline{D(0,1)}$, we have $|z|>1$. I think this, along with other properties, can be used to show that $|\frac{z^k}{1-z^k}|>$ some known divergent series term but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @prets Yes!!  I was unaware of this post. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I found it by searching for the series using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/). It's a useful tool.

Comment: @prets Thanks for the info!